# Validação model sempre falha

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-validation

Tenho os seguintes modelos:

```
public class Local {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
 }

public class Grupo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? LocalId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocalId")]
    public virtual Local Local { get; set; }
}
```

No meu controller antes de validar a model e adicionar ao banco eu informo a `id` do `Local` através de uma **session**.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult _Create(Grupo model)
    {
        model.LocalId = SessionContext.LocalSelecionado;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _service.Add(model);
            return RedirectToAction("_List");
        }

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Toda vez a validação falha dizendo que o `LocalId` é obrigatório, e é, mas eu estou colocando o valor, no breakpoint se eu olho o **locals** da **model** está lá o valor e ainda assim falha.

A única forma que consegui fazer é no formulário botando um campo com nome `LocalId` e trazendo o valor do formulário dai ele também continua reconhecendo e a validação não falha.

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois o Model só é validado antes do Controller ser executado, alterar o valor do model não vai mudar o valor do `ModelState.IsValid`

No seu caso você poderia tirar o `[Required]` do `LocalId` já que não é requerido o preenchimento deste campo pelo usuário, ele vai ser preenchido pelo seu programa.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. No caso eu poderia retirar o required ou apenas tirar o nullable do LocalId. Eu gosto de usar o Required pra gerar as migrations. Tirando o nullable do LocalId falha a inserção no banco e é exatamente isso que estou buscando.

Comment: Eu não testei, mas você pode tentar trocar o `if (ModelState.IsValid)` por `if (TryValidateModel(model))`, o detalhe ai é que me parece que este método valida apenas o objeto passado para ele, se entendi corretamente o funcionamento dele poderia acontecer por exemplo dele não validar a sua classe `Local` caso ela tivesse alguma regra de validação

Comment: Sim, poderia também revalidar a model mas não há necessidade no meu caso. Com o required eu gero nullables nas migrations e se o formulário não tiver o campo e eu não inserir manualmente nos testes de telas automáticos vai falhar, se falhar é porque no controller eu esqueci de setar a id, era isso que eu precisava!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte método: ModelState.Clear(); para limpar o estado do modelo e reexecutar o ModelState.IsValid.

ModelState.Clear() faz uma revalidação baseado no model populado atualmente, já com suas alterações após o envio do formulário, já na Action. Seu método ficaria assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult _Create(Grupo model)
{
    model.LocalId = SessionContext.LocalSelecionado;

    ModelState.Clear();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _service.Add(model);
        return RedirectToAction("_List");
    }

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: Sim, obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Não tenho certeza quanto a isso, mas se não me engano o Clear vai remover todos os erros encontrados na hora da validação e assim o IsValid vai passar a retornar true, porém ele não vai revalidar o model

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa entendo sua preocupação, mas nos testes que fiz, ele revalidou, caso ainda haja dados que devem ser validados os erros ainda são retornados.